# I'm not getting Remote Notification data after Local Notification is showed

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

In my application i'hv implemented both local and remote notification, both are working fine.

I'hv implement local notification from this **[Link](https://www.simplifiedios.net/ios-local-notification-tutorial/)** same code.

Now, My App is in Foreground mode and i'm firing push notification, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is called n i'm passing push notification's data to local notification and then local notification appear.

My problem is, app still in foreground mode, i'm firing push notification again, im receiving push notification **But** my `didReceiveRemoteNotification` not getting called. this happen only after i showing my local notification.

Does anyone have any idea about this issue ?

I'm using Xcode 9.0.1, iOS version 12.2.6

**Any Yes I'm Using Real iPhone Device not Simulator**

Comment: Try to use real device replace the iOS simulator ?

Comment: @LeonardoHammer dude push notification not work in simulator and i know already. lol ;)